# For given $σ, σ_1, σ_2, . . . ∈ L^d,$ ($L^d$ set of all signed measures) we should show that $\lim_{n}σ_n = σ ⇔ ∀A ∈ F, \; \lim_{n} σ_n(A) = σ(A).$

Tags: probability-theory, signed-measures

For given $σ, σ_1, σ_2, . . . ∈ L^d,$ ($L^d$ set of all signed measures) we should show that
$$\lim_{n}σ_n = σ ⇔ ∀A ∈ F, \; \lim_{n} σ_n(A) = σ(A).$$

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: What notion of convergence are you using? And is this over a finite space? If we're talking about weak convergence of measures, the above is not even true for positive probability measures on a general measure space.

Comment: Over a finite space and convergence defined as $\Omega=\{\omega_1,...,\omega_N\}$, then $\lim_{n}\sigma_n=\sigma \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n}(\sigma_n(\omega_1),...,\sigma_n(\omega_N))=(\sigma(\omega_1)),...,\sigma(\omega_N))$